# Issue matching string date to compare with with dates in database?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find all users that have a matching birthday stored in the format **"1975-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00"**

When I send a date of type String to my route and convert it to a date with **new Date(req.body.DOB)**
I am getting a date with an additional 4 hours: **"1975-01-12T04:00:00.000Z"** and a Z at the end.

I am new with dates so not too sure what is going on. How can I convert the string date into a date in the same way it is saved in my database, without the additional 4 hours and Z?

```
router.post("/api/date", async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const birthdate = new Date(req.body.DOB) // String as "01-12-1975"

    const users = await User.find({
      DOB: birthdate,
    })

    res.status(200).send(users)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases typically use iso_8601 date format, which includes timezone. Javascript dates use the system timezone upon instantiation, if you use a format which omits the timezone (like the one you have). This is why there is an offset of 4 (offset from UTC timezone), presumably your server is in Russia or something.

You should convert the string to ISO format before converting to a date object. For example, if you store all birthdays as UTC time (at midnight), then you can just convert it like so:

```
const dateStr = "01-12-1975"
const [date, month, year] = dateStr.split('-')
const isoStr = `${year}-${month}-${date}T00:00:00.000Z`
const newDate = new Date(isoStr) // 1975-12-01T00:00:00.000Z
```